# Pentaho: Image in Pentaho form

Tags: pentaho, pentaho-design-studio

I want to fetch image from local path (i.e: C:/Users/myname/sample.jpg). 
Already tried with image icon on left of the form and set the value from the above both but the thing is i need to set the image from external . Like property file or kettle file.
please help me on this.im using Pentaho Designer 5.3.0

thanks in advance

Comment: Not clear? What do you mean by external? local path worked?

Comment: need to get image location from a property file

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the location of the image from a property file, you have to think about how to get that value and take it to the report, that you can do with a kettle transformation, that takes the value you want from the properties file and send it to a Report, in the pdi there is a step called Pentaho Reporting Ouput, which makes a call to the report, to this you will pass as parameter the location of the image that you want to be displayed (the name of the parameter in the pdi and in the Report designes must be the same), you can do the following:

1. Create a parameter, which will be of type string, this will be the parameter will receive the location of the image on the disk
2. Add an image field instead of an image, and pass the parameter you created as a value

After you can upload the image you want, just pass the physical address to the report from the pdi.

I hope I help you

[image: generar reporte con imagen]